# Convolution and convolution transposed do not cancel each other

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement an autoencoder CNN. However, I have the following problem:

The last convolutional layer of my encoder is defined as follows:

```
Conv2d(128, 256, 3, padding=1, stride=2)
```

The input of this layer has shape (1, 128, 24, 24). Thus, the output has shape (1, 256, 12, 12).

After this layer, I have ReLU activation and BatchNorm. Neither of these changes the shape of the output.

Then I have a first ConvTranspose2d layer defined as:

```
ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 3, padding=1, stride=2)
```

But the output of this layer has shape (1, 128, 23, 23).

As far as I know, if we use the same kernel size, stride, and padding in ConvTrapnpose2d as in the preceding Conv2d layer, then the output of this 2 layers block must have the same shape as its input.

So, my question is: what is wrong with my understanding? And how can I fix this issue?

Comment: The only solution I can see so far is to use `output_padding`. Also, it looks like this 'cancel' rule does not work for even inputs and outputs with even stride.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first like to note that the `nn.ConvTranspose2d` layer is not the inverse of `nn.Conv2d` as explained in its documentation page:

> it is not an actual deconvolution operation as **it does not compute a true inverse of convolution**

---

> As far as I know, if we use the same kernel size, stride, and padding in `ConvTranspose2d` as in the preceding Conv2d layer, then the output of this 2 layers block must have the same shape as its input.

This is not always true! It depends on the input spatial dimensions.

In terms of *spatial dimensions* the 2D convolution will output:

```
out = [(x + 2p - d(k - 1) - 1)/s + 1]
```

where `[x]` is the whole part of `x`.

while the 2D transpose convolution will output:

```
out = (x - 1)s - 2p + d(k - 1) + op + 1
```

where `x = input_dimension`, `out = output_dimension`, `k = kernel_size`, `s = stride`, `d = dilation`, `p = padding`, and `op = output_padding`.

If you look at the `convT o conv` operator (*i.e.* `convT(conv(x))`) then you have:

```
out = (out_conv - 1)s - 2p + d(k - 1) + op + 1
    = ([(x + 2p - d(k - 1) - 1)/s + 1] - 1)s - 2p + d(k - 1) + op + 1
```

Which equals to `x` only if we have `[(x + 2p - d(k - 1) - 1)/s + 1] = (x + 2p - d(k - 1) - 1)/s + 1`, that is: if `x` is *odd*, in this case:

```
out = ((x + 2p - d(k - 1) - 1)/s + 1 - 1)s - 2p + d(k - 1) + op + 1
    = x + op
```

And `out = x` when `op = 0`.

Otherwise if `x` is *even* then:

```
out = x - 1 + op
```

And setting `op = 1` gives `out = x`.

---

Here is an example:

```
>>> conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1)

>>> convT = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
>>> convT(conv(torch.rand(1, 1, 25, 25))).shape # x even
(1, 1, 25, 25) #<- out = x

>>> convT = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
>>> convT(conv(torch.rand(1, 1, 24, 24))).shape # x odd
(1, 1, 24, 24) #<- out = x - 1 + op
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I've to point out that there is a small error related to the even odd argument: your argument relies on the stride=2 and kernel is odd, if you set kernel=2, then the parity argument switches. However, the spirit is correct.